# Polymer.js components on Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox, polymer

I am having a problem on Firefox with Polymer.js.

This is my Polymer element.

```
<!-- Imports polymer -->
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<!-- Defines element markup -->
<dom-module id="scoreboard-bar">
    ...
    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: 'scoreboard-bar',
            properties: {
                totalCounter: {
                    type: Number,
                    value: 0
                },
            },
            getTotalCounter: function () {
                return this.totalCounter;
            },
            setTotalCounter: function (totalCounter) {
                this.totalCounter = totalCounter;
            },
        });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

This is the import of the Polymer component into the main html file:

```
<head>
    <!-- Imports polyfill -->
    <script src="{% static "polymer/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js" %}">  </script>

    <!-- Imports custom elements -->
    <link rel="import" href="{% static "polymer/components/entity-vibeboard/scoreboard-bar.html" %}">
</head>
```

To set up the counter just on load the page I have:

```
<body>
    <div>
        <scoreboard-bar id="scoreboardBarFlag"></scoreboard-bar>
    </div>

    <script>
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            var scoreboardBarFlagPolymer = document.querySelector('#scoreboardBarFlag');
            scoreboardBarFlagPolymer.setTotalCounter(10);
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

This code is working perfectly on Google Chrome, but it's not working on Firefox. The error that I am receiving is:

```
TypeError: scoreboardBarFlagPolymer.setTotalCounter is not a function
```

If I add a breakpoint on the Firebug, doing a debug, the function is available on the Polymer component, but it's not available just after load the page.

I think the error it's because the javascript function is trying to set the counter before to load the Polymer component on the page.

Any idea how can I run the javascript function after load the all Polymer components on the page? The issue it's only on Firefox, on Chrome it's working fine.

Comment: I suspect that Chrome works as it has native support for an early draft of the Web Components specs, and thus doesn't need the polyfill. Specifically, the HTML import will be blocking in Chrome, so once the DOM is loaded, it's ready to go. Other browsers have to wait for the polyfill to do its magic. Instead of using `$(document).ready(...)`, try adding a listener for the [polymer-ready event](http://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/polymer/polymer.html#polymer-ready).

Comment: polymer-ready has been removed in newer versions of Polymer. WebComponentsReady should be used instead. Source: https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/1381

Comment: Whoops, looks like polymer-ready is deprecated in favor of WebComponentsReady as of Polymer 0.8. [Discussion on GitHub](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/1381)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try listening to the `WebComponentsReady` event as described [in the documentation of webcomponents.js](https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs#webcomponentsready)

```
window.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function(e) {
  // imports are loaded and elements have been registered
  console.log('Components are ready');
});
```